# Why does loading an extrnal JS file break the page's styling?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a situation where an external js file is loaded on the page depending on a query parameter. The file contains UI components and their styles. When the file loads, it breaks the page's styling.

What I am struggling to understand is why the page elements have the same css classes but appear different.

#### Without the JS file

[image]

#### With the JS file

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading a new JavaScript file that has `<style>` tags embedded within it. These are denoted by the `inline` styles you seen in your images.

Because the styles that are already on the page are at an `inline` level as *well*, they tie with the new styles in terms of [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). As such, rules that are applied **last** (by the conditionally added JavaScript file) **override** those that are applied first (in the base document). This can be seen by the strikethroughs in your image. Those rules are getting loaded, but are being overridden.